ESP32 ink display not showing text
Im new to esp32 and try to show some text on an E-ink display from waveshare. The problem is the text is not displayed.
display: "WaveShare 2.66 inch 396x152 black and white" https://www.waveshare.com/product/displays/e-paper/2.66inch-e-paper-module.htm?___SID=U
esp board: "esp32-s3-devkitc-1" https://www.amazon.com.be/-/nl/dp/B09D3S7T3M?asc_campaign=4ae5e6e2ca0fb9a1b8d827e5f3703a8f&asc_source=01H1P39M5ZSG9J6WR6B1HBK9M0
My pin configuration on the board is as followed:

BUSY: 9
RST: 12
DC: 11
CS: 10
CLK: 14
DIN: 13
GND: Gnd
VCC: 3v3

my main.cpp file:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <GxEPD2_BW.h>
#include <Fonts/FreeMonoBold9pt7b.h>


#define CS_PIN   10    
#define EPD_DC   11    
#define RST_PIN  12    
#define BUSY_PIN 9     

GxEPD2_BW<GxEPD2_266_BN, GxEPD2_266_BN::HEIGHT> display(GxEPD2_266_BN(CS_PIN, EPD_DC, RST_PIN, BUSY_PIN));

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  display.init(115200);
  
  delay(1000); 

  display.setFullWindow();
  display.setRotation(1); 
  display.setTextColor(GxEPD_BLACK);
  
  display.fillScreen(GxEPD_WHITE);
  
  display.setCursor(10, 30);
  display.setFont(&FreeMonoBold9pt7b); 
  display.print("Hello World");
  
  display.display();
}

void loop() {

}

platform.io.ini:
; PlatformIO Project Configuration File
;
;   Build options: build flags, source filter
;   Upload options: custom upload port, speed and extra flags
;   Library options: dependencies, extra library storages
;   Advanced options: extra scripting
;
; Please visit documentation for the other options and examples
; https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf.html

[env:esp32-s3-devkitc-1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-s3-devkitc-1
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = esptool
upload_port = COM16
monitor_port = COM16
monitor_speed = 115200
upload_speed = 921600
lib_deps = 
    adafruit/Adafruit GFX Library@^1.11.11
    adafruit/Adafruit NeoPixel@^1.12.3
    adafruit/Adafruit BusIO@^1.16.2
    zinggjm/GxEPD2@^1.5.9

thanks in advance,

Your code missed quite some setups that need to be done. See the library example.
